# Как программно создавать атрибуты и добавлять их значения для товаров в WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Программно добавляются **товары в WooCommerce**, необходимо что бы еще **добавлялись атрибуты и их значения для товаров**. 
Написал такой код:

```
private function _product_set_attributes($product_id, $_params)
    {
        if (count($_params)) {
            foreach ($_params as $_param) {
                $_param_atts = $_param->attributes();
                $_name = (string) $_param_atts->name;
                $_pa_name = 'pa_' . wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name($_name);
                $_value = (string) $_param;

                $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $_value, $_pa_name, true );

                if ( is_wp_error($term_taxonomy_ids) ) {
                    $attribute_id = wc_create_attribute(array(
                        'name' => $_name,
                    ));
                    if (!is_wp_error($attribute_id)) {
                        $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $_value, $_pa_name, true );
                    }
                }

                $_attributes[$_name] = array( 
                    'name'=>$_pa_name, 
                    'value'=>$_value,
                    'is_visible' => '1',
                    'is_variation' => '1',
                    'is_taxonomy' => '1'
                );

            }
            if (is_array($_attributes) and count($_attributes)) {
                update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $_attributes);
            }
        }
    }
```

**атрибуты создаются - только дублируются** - видимо нужно добавить проверку на существование атрибуты чтобы не добавлять его еще раз, так же **у товаров проставляются эти атрибуты но без указанных значений**

**поделитесь кодом или подскажите что я не так сделал?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для добавления аттрибутов к товару во первых вам надо работать с товаром `WC_Product` и добавлять к нему массив аттрибутов `WC_Product_Attribute`. Это выглядит как-то так:

```
$product = new WC_Product( $product_id );

// Example attributes.
$attributes = [
    'attr1' => 'Attr name',
    'attr2' => 'Attr name',
]
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute => $option ) {
    $pa = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    $pa->set_name( sanitize_text_field( $attribute ) );
    $pa->set_options( [ $option ] );
    $pa->set_visible( true );
    $attributes[ $attribute ] = $pa;
}

$product->set_attributes( array_values( $attributes ) );
$product->save();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите в массиве $attributes ключ = наименование атрибута, а значение - это значение атрибута для товара? Т.е. к примеру есть у нас атрибут "Размер" равный допустим: 30 для товара, соотв. будет: $attributes = ['Размер' => 30] всё верно?

Comment: Размер - name атрибута. 30 - это options атрибута

Comment: а еще не подскажите, как сделать так чтобы атрибут был вариативным и указать кол-во вариативного товара на складе именно с привязкой к этому атрибуту?

Answer (score 0):

Для меня сработал этот код

```
$updated_attributes = array(
    'pa_bpm' => array(124),
    'pa_daw' => array('Fl stydio')
);

$product_attributes = array();
foreach ($updated_attributes as $taxonomy => $terms) {
    $term_ids = array();

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_id = wp_set_object_terms($product->get_id(), $term, $taxonomy, true);

        if (!is_wp_error($term_id)) {
            $term_ids[] = $term_id[0];
        }
    }


    foreach ($updated_attributes as $taxonomy => $terms) {
        $product_attributes[$taxonomy] = array(
            'name' => $taxonomy,
            'value' => implode(',', $term_ids),
            'is_visible' => '1',
            'is_variation' => '0',
            'is_taxonomy' => '1'
        );
    }

}
$tmpBk = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_product_attributes', true) 
    ? get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_product_attributes', true) : [];
update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_product_attributes', array_merge($tmpBk, $product_attributes));
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет